# Bluetooth pemissions in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, bluetooth, permission-denied

I want to request BLUETOOTH_SCAN and BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission. Could anyone tell me how should I do that in Kotlin? I have this piece of code but it always tells permission denied.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 var requestBluetooth = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

private val requestMultiplePermissions =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        permissions.entries.forEach {
            Log.d("test", "${it.key} = ${it.value}")
          }
    }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button) // just a simple button from XML file

    button.setOnClickListener  { 

        // for android 12
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            requestMultiplePermissions.launch(arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT))
          }
        else{
            val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            requestBluetooth.launch(enableBtIntent)
          }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How does your manifest look like?

Answer (score 0):

Because I am not yet well-versed in Kotlin (and I expect you to be able to easily convert the Java codes into Kotlin), I'll just show you how to request the dangerous ***Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT*** permission every time we want to access the list of paired Bluetooth devices:

```java
    public static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_CONNECT = 101; //the int value must be unique

    public boolean checkBluetoothConnectPermission(Activity activity) {
        boolean permitted = false;

        Boolean bluetoothAlreadyGranted = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) ? 
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, 
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED: true;

        Log.i(IMapView.LOGTAG, 
            String.format("PERMISSION: checkBluetoothPermission(%s) bluetoothAlreadyGranted=%s", 
                activity.getClass().getSimpleName(), 
                bluetoothAlreadyGranted));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            // Check for permission
            if (!bluetoothAlreadyGranted.booleanValue()) {

                bluetoothAlreadyGranted = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, 
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);

                // Check for permission
                if (bluetoothAlreadyGranted.booleanValue()) {

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainApp.getCurrentActivity(), R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle)
                            .setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.bluetooth_connect_rational_title, 
                                activity.getString(R.string.app_name_flavor)))
                            .setMessage(activity.getString(R.string.bluetooth_connect_rational_message, 
                                activity.getString(R.string.app_name_flavor)))
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT},
                                            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
                                }
                            })
                            .create()
                            .show();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT},
                            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
                }
            } else {
                permitted = true;
            }
        } else {
            permitted = true;
        }

        return permitted;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

        // Check if permission was granted
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        //boolean granted = grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED; //@TODO you need to check which permission from the array to get the granted status for the matched request code...

        switch (requestCode) {

            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_CONNECT: {
                //do whatever you want here
            }
            break;

        }
    }
```

In the Android manifest, the following entry shall be provided:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
```

The same shall apply for the dangerous ***Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN*** permission with a different intent request code.

Comment: Hello ecle. Thanks for your response but it still doesn't work. I've already tried your piece of code but nothing happens. Moreover I know this method of requesting dangerous permissions and I check it out for bluetooth but it wasn't working. I don't have any problem with requesting other permissions this way. READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE which is also considered as dangerous can be requested by this method with ease. What about bluetooth permission? What is the difference between Storage and Bluetooth? Why this first works and the second doesn't It still remains a question for me...